# How to convert pandas series with numpy array values to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

1. I have a pandas series which values are numpy array. For simplicity, say

```
    series = pd.Series([np.array([1,2,3,4]), np.array([5,6,7,8]), np.array([9,10,11,12])], index=['file1', 'file2', 'file3'])
```

```
file1       [1, 2, 3, 4]
file2       [5, 6, 7, 8]
file3    [9, 10, 11, 12]
```

How can I expand it to a dataframe of the form `df_concatenated`:

```
       0   1   2   3
file1  1   2   3   4
file2  5   6   7   8
file3  9  10  11  12
```

2. A wider version of the same problem. Actually the `series` is obtained from a different dataframe of the form:

DataFrame:

```
              0   1
file  slide        
file1 1       1   2
      2       3   4
file2 1       5   6
      2       7   8
file3 1       9  10
      2      11  12
```

by grouping on 'file' index with concatenation of columns.

```
   def concat_sublevel(data):
        return np.concatenate(data.values)

   series = data.groupby(level=[0]).apply(concat_sublevel)
```

May be somebody see a better way to come from dataframe `data` to  `df_concatenated`.

Caveat. `slide` sub-index can have different number of values for different `file` values. In such a case I need to repeat one of the rows to get the same dimensions in all resulting rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try of using pandas Dataframe from records

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(series.values,index=series.index)
```

Out:

```
    0   1   2   3
file1   1   2   3   4
file2   5   6   7   8
file3   9   10  11  12
```

Comment: Equivalent alternative: `pd.DataFrame(series.values.tolist(), index=series.index)`

Comment: Great! Thank you